# Create a view by Joining multiple index tables as one SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, view

I am trying to join multiple index table to my fact table please see my tables below

**Facts Table**

| ID | Name | Country | ProjectStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nico | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | Carlo | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | Addie | 0 | 2 |

**CountryTable**

| ID | Value | IndexValue | Language |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mexico | 0 | EN |
| 2 | Mexico_KR | 0 | KR |
| 3 | Mexico_JP | 0 | JP |
| 4 | Singapore | 1 | EN |
| 5 | Singapore_KR | 1 | KR |
| 6 | Singapore_JP | 1 | JP |
| 4 | Australia | 2 | EN |
| 5 | Australia_KR | 2 | KR |
| 6 | Australia_JP | 2 | JP |

**ProjectStatusTable**

| ID | Value | IndexValue | Language |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Not Started | 0 | EN |
| 2 | Not Started_KR | 0 | KR |
| 3 | Not Started_JP | 0 | JP |
| 4 | In Progress | 1 | EN |
| 5 | In Progress_KR | 1 | KR |
| 6 | In Progress_JP | 1 | JP |
| 4 | Complete | 2 | EN |
| 5 | Complete_KR | 2 | KR |
| 6 | Complete_JP | 2 | JP |

**Output
as view**

| ID | Name | Country | ProjectStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nico | Singapore | Not Started |
| 2 | Carlo | Australia | In Progress |
| 3 | Addie | Mexico | Complete |

Comment: Well, that's a pretty basic 3-way-join query, what have you tried so far and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: Why is the ID value of your table duplicates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are looking for a way to join facts table with top 1 row of each group of countries and projects, in this case you can use `cross apply` :

```
select f.ID, f.Name, cts.Value as Country, prj.Value as ProjectStatus
from FactsTable f
cross apply (
  select top 1 Value
  from CountryTable
  where IndexValue = f.Country
  order by ID
) as cts
cross apply (
  select top 1 Value
  from ProjectStatusTable
  where IndexValue = f.ProjectStatus
  order by ID
) as prj
```

Results :

| ID | Name | Country | ProjectStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nico | Singapore | Not Started |
| 2 | Carlo | Australia | In Progress |
| 3 | Addie | Mexico | Complete |

If you want the English values not the first values then :

```
select f.ID, f.Name, c.Value as Country, p.Value as ProjectStatus
from FactsTable f
inner join CountryTable c on c.IndexValue = f.Country and c.Language = 'EN'
inner join ProjectStatusTable p on p.IndexValue = f.ProjectStatus and p.Language = 'EN'
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/nVhgHUIR)

Comment: I assume OP wants the English values, not the first values. But the question isn't clear about that though.

Comment: Yes could be, thanks for the remark @jarlh

Comment: Do I just remove the Language filter to get everything? 
This table will feed into PowerBI where user can switch between languages.

Comment: This is require an other question, Please ask another question and include a detailed description and a reproducible example to support it. I'm sure you will get an answer.